# Is it possible to trigger a fusion table to geocode without using gui?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have done fusion-table map for a customer. I am updating the table rows with server scripts, sometimes I need to delete all the rows and then create new rows. None of my data comes with geocoded addresses.
This map is shown in my client website, all updating is done in a server script.

So, my question is once I update the data, the map doesn't update with the new data until I log into the fusion table and I manually trigger a geocode.

Is it possible to trigger that remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't trigger the FT geocoder remotely, but you can use the same Google Maps API to first geocode your addresses, then add them and their coordinates to the table. You can see an example of this in [Synchronizing Fusion Tables with Google Forms](https://cdn.rawgit.com/fusiontables/fusion-tables-api-samples/master/FusionTablesFormSync/docs/reference.html).